# How to create an element with special behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

I'm trying to make an element with special interface and behavior.

for example I have an `input` in my page.

```
<input type='text' po-type='multiinput' value='' />
```

and I want to add some tags after my inputs with `po-type='multiinput'` attribute.

I tried this code in my page load event:

```
$("input[po-type='multiinput']").after("<div>my details</div>");
```

the problem is, when I'm using ajax to load elements with this attr, that way is use less.

question is:

How can I force browser to add `my details` after this kind of elements in every way?

I don't want to use a function every times after adding some input. I want every thing automated.

thanks for every answers you can provide.

Comment: use `data-*` for this issue as attributes

Comment: adding an `attr` is not my problem. how can i use it?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/mVeW6/ here i use title with data : `data-title` you can add as many as you want and then can retrieve them as in fiddle :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't make an attribute `po-type`. The HTML5 standard allows `data-*` as an attribute. See http://www.marcofolio.net/webdesign/html5_data-_attributes_are_great_and_you_know_it.html for more info. 
Make `$("input[data-potype='multiinput']").after("<div>my details</div>");` a `success` or `complete` callback of your `$.ajax` See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for that.